# Add extra row to dataframe based on values of other rows

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe with two rows of data. I would like to add a third row with values representing the difference between the previous two.

The data is in the following format:

```
Month   A   B   C   D   E   F
Jan     1   2   4   8   4   1
Feb     1   1   4   5   2   0
```

I would like to add an extra row with a calculation to give the change across the two months:

```
Month   A   B   C   D   E   F
Jan     1   2   4   8   4   1
Feb     1   1   4   5   2   0
Change  0   1   0   3   2   1
```

I've been looking at various functions to add additional rows including `rbind` and `mutate` but I'm struggling to perform the calculation in the newly created row.

Comment: **Self Promotion**: You could use the developer version of a [package](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop) I wrote: `manymodelr::rowdiff(df[,-1])[1,]`.

Comment: Is `Month` column the 1st one? Can you check output of `df[1, -1] - df[2, -1]` ? Does it give you right numbers?

Comment: @RonakShah solved it, the issue was with the `Month = "Change"` argument - r didn't like have date and text values in the same column

Comment: @NelsonGon  You could post that as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's just two rows you can subtract the individual rows and `rbind` the difference

```
rbind(df, data.frame(Month = "Change", df[1, -1] - df[2, -1]))

#   Month A B C D E F
#1    Jan 1 2 4 8 4 1
#2    Feb 1 1 4 5 2 0
#3 Change 0 1 0 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d1<-data.frame(Month = "Change" , df[1,-1] , df[2,-1])
newdf <- rbind(df,d1)
```

This will create a new data-frame with what you require

Comment: Isn't this exactly same as my post?

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, diff) %>%
    abs %>%
    bind_rows(df1, .) %>%
    mutate(Month = replace_na(Month, "Change"))
#   Month A B C D E F
#1    Jan 1 2 4 8 4 1
#2    Feb 1 1 4 5 2 0
#3 Change 0 1 0 3 2 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Month = c("Jan", "Feb"), A = c(1L, 1L), B = 2:1, 
    C = c(4L, 4L), D = c(8L, 5L), E = c(4L, 2L), F = 1:0),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```